# Return next row that meets condition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

I can't find a solution to the following problem.
Assuming I have 2 tables:

*Table 1*:

```
Name        | Age      
Nick        | 52      
Adam        | 52      
Monica      | 40
```

*Table 2*:

```
Name        | Task       | Value  | Done
Nick        | Clean      | 010000 | Y
Nick        |            | 011000 |
Nick        |            | 020000 | 
Nick        | Vacuum     | 025000 | 
Nick        | Do Dishes  | 030000 | 
Adam        |            | 010000 |
Adam        | Clean      | 015000 | Y
Adam        | Dust       | 030000 | Y
Adam        | Cook       | 035000 | 
Monica      | PaintHouse | 010000 |
Monica      | Garbage    | 020000 |
```

*What I'm looking for is this*:

How can I write an SQL that gives me the result of all everyone that is 52 and shows the next task he/she has to do, skipping all the empty entries in "task"
Output should look something like:

```
Name        | Age     | Task 
Nick        | 52      | Vacuum
Adam        | 52      | Cook
```

Database is 2000 version of MS SQL Server.
Also, I don't have any write access, only read access.

UPDATE:
In the original post, I posted:

```
Adam        | Cook       | 030000
```

This was not correct It should have been:

```
Adam        | Cook       | 035000
```

I have corrected this error.

Comment: How do you determine the 'next' task?  It 'looks' like you're using 'Value' to determine some sort of ordering.  However, if Adam had not already done 'Dust', how would you know whether the next task was Dust or Cook since they both have the same 'Value'?  Also, I've never heard of Sql Server 2002.

Comment: The way you present this data makes it impossible to come up to that resultset. Look `select * from #Tasks inner join #Names on #Tasks.name = #Names.name where 
#Names.age = 52 and #Tasks.task != ''` thats as close as you'll get but then because you lack an autoinc key or `DateAdded` sort of timestamp its just not possible to accurately determine what was the last Task performed.

Comment: 2002? Did you mean 2000? Or 2012? I don't think there's a 2002 version.

Comment: I mean version 2000

Answer (score 1):

This answer returns your desired result and it should run on SQL-Server 2000, but it is not valid until you are not able to set a **Task order**.

> ```
> SELECT t1.Name, t1.Age,
>        (SELECT TOP 1 t2.Task
>         FROM   t2
>         WHERE  t2.Name = t1.Name 
>         AND    t2.Task IS NOT NULL
>         AND    (t2.Done IS NULL OR t2.Done <> 'Y')) Task
> FROM   t1
> WHERE  t1.Age = 52
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> Name | Age | Task  
> :--- | --: | :-----
> Nick |  52 | Vacuum
> Adam |  52 | Cook
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=f9e21a24fd628f04c5bfab7a352c9853)*

**UPDATE**

According to the dbfiddle supplied by the OP:

> ```
> SELECT t1.P_No,
>        ISNULL((SELECT   TOP 1 t2.Task
>                FROM     t2
>                WHERE    t2.P_No = t1.P_No 
>                AND      t2.Task <> ''
>                AND      t2.No <> '0'
>                ORDER BY t2.P_No, t2.Value), '') AS Task
> FROM   t1
> WHERE  t1.Status <> 3
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> P_No | Task     
> :--- | :--------
> P1   |          
> P2   | Do Dishes
> P4   |          
> P6   |          
> P8   |          
> P10  | Do Dishes
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=0c62fa5e09a97e12bef43b256b1f42b4)*

Comment: I tried you sollution, but when executing this in my own Databasebrowser, I get the error message "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WITH'"

Comment: I'll modify it later, SQL2000 doesn't allow this solution.

Comment: I see, thank you. Can this solution be "modified" to work with version 2000? Because I dried your solution and dbfiddle and it works perfectly (in the new version)

Comment: 2000 doesn't allow neither CTE functions nor row_number functions

Comment: I'm really feeling like a noob (which I am in respect to SQL :)), but I can't figure out why this doesn't work. I created a dbfiddle myself (dbfiddle is great, didn't know it existed!!)
http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=66f53119afbc779d4ef2cea673d72610
I extended a bit on your proposed solution with more kind of real life data.
Result isn't what I expected.
Should be:
P1 --> Clean (Since all No's are 0)
P2 --> Clean (Since this is the next process, following ('P2','Cook','4500000','11')

Comment: I'll take a look but you should consider to add an order field, if not, you cannot be sure of the order returned by the server.

Comment: You have changed the conditions, what `No` means? Should I select first task where `No <> 0`?  P2 has two tasks with No <> 0 what is the desired row?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use outer apply which will cross reference the table Table02 with Name and order by Value ASC showing top (1) rows.

```
drop table if exists dbo.Table01;
drop table if exists dbo.Table02;

create table dbo.Table01 (
    Name varchar(100)
    , age int
);

create table dbo.Table02 (
    Name varchar(100)
    , Task varchar(100)
    , Value varchar(100)
    , Done char(1)
);


insert into dbo.Table01 (Name, Age)
values ('Nick', 52), ('Adam', 52), ('Monica', 40);

insert into dbo.Table02 (Name, Task, Value, Done)
values ('Nick', 'clean', '010000', 'Y')
    , ('Nick', '', '011000', '')
    , ('Nick', '', '020000', '')
    , ('Nick', 'Vacuum', '025000', '')
    , ('Nick', 'Do Dishes', '030000', '')
    , ('Adam', '', '010000', '')
    , ('Adam', 'Clean', '015000', 'Y')
    , ('Adam', 'Dust', '030000', 'Y')
    , ('Adam', 'Cook', '030000', '')
    , ('Monica', 'PaintHouse', '010000', '')
    , ('Monica', 'Garbage', '020000', '');

select
*
from dbo.Table01 t01
    outer apply (
            select
                top (1)
                t02.Task
            from dbo.Table02 t02
            where t01.Name = t02.Name
                and isnull(t02.Done, '') <> 'Y'
                and isnull(t02.Task, '') <> ''
            order by t02.Value asc
    ) tn
where t01.age = 52
```

Comment: Hi Dean,
When trying your sollution, I get the error message "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'outer' "

Comment: @Stefan What version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This should work in 2000, too:

```
select
   *,
   (select top 1 Task 
    from Table02 as t2
    where t1.name = t2.name -- correlate both tables
      and t2.Task <> ''
      and Done <> 'Y'  -- ?? seems to be what you want
    order by Task      -- ?? whatever you need to determine the "next" task (maybe no order at all)
   )
from Table01 as t1
where age = 52
```